# Vector space - 3 no zero vectors in R^7

Tags: linear-algebra

I read the video from MIT linear algebra class. There is a question, what's the dimension of a subspace of 3 no zero vector spanned in R^7? Like U, V, W in R^7.

Comment: there is no matrix here to have column space and row space; it sounds like the question is about the dimension of the subspace spanned by the three non-zero vectors

Comment: Your question is mixed up.  Perhaps state in the exact words of the video?

Comment: Do you mean, what is the dimension of the subspace spanned by three non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^7$? If so this question requires additional information to be answerable. Specifically, you need to know if there exists a non-trivial relation among the three vectors.

Comment: @NoahSolomon:  before OP edited the question, it said the answer is "$1$ or $2$ or $3$"